# Why is XCode unable to find TensorflowListC.framework?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to run the code in this GitHub repo, https://github.com/JaeHeee/FlutterWithMediaPipe.

However, when I try to build for iOS either from Flutter or directly in XCode, I get linker errors that TensorFlowLite.framework cannot be found.

Things I have tried --

1. I have followed the instructions available here https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter/versions/0.9.0 to put the .framework file in what should be the correct spot
2. Set a direct linker dependency in XCode for the Target that is throwing the error to the .framework file. Image:
   [image: xcode linker settings]
3. Normal build clean commands etc restarting that are sometimes necessary to force the UI/cmd line tools out of a bad state

What can I do to get the build process to find this dependency?

(Also, I realize tflite_flutter has newer versions that dynamically link TF. When the team rewrote the library, they deprecated the tflite_flutter_helper lib that the above repo heavily depends, and to this point have not provided a replacement; so any answer that revolves around updating the dependency version is a non-starter.)